# How to add sibling inline

Tags: jquery, html, css

```js
$("#sibling").prepend("#sibling2")
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="sibling">First sibling</div>
<div>Another component</div>
<div id="sibling2">Second sibling</div>
```

I tried to add the first sibling to the second sibling by prepending.

Although it adds, but on top of the second sibling.
I want to add the first sibling beside the second sibling.

Comment: did you try `append` ?

Comment: @trichetriche: That would do the same thing, just in the wrong order.

Comment: This has nothing to do with jQuery or JavaScript, it's a CSS issue. You need to style the `div`s so they aren't block elements, since block elements extend the full width of their container. You could make them inline blocks, or apply a float, or...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two ways to make this, in the first case you could use [insertBefore()](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/html_insertbefore.asp) method, and if you want them togheter inline just apply `inline-block` style:

```js
$("#sibling").insertBefore("#sibling2")
```

```css
div{
  border: 1px solid black;
}
#sibling, #sibling2{
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="sibling">First sibling</div>
<div>Another component</div>
<div id="sibling2">Second sibling</div>
```

In the second case you can use [prepend()](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/html_prepend.asp) method wich move the `#sibling` inside at the begginning of `#sibling2`, check the example:

```js
$('#sibling2').prepend($('#sibling'));
```

```css
div{
  border: 1px solid black;
}
#sibling, #sibling2{
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="sibling">First sibling</div>
<div>Another component</div>
<div id="sibling2">Second sibling</div>
```

Comment: Glad to help you.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to add the first sibling beside the second sibling.

Provide `inline-block` display CSS for the required `div`s as per the following code snippets.

```js
$(function() {
  $('#sibling2').prepend($('#sibling'));
});
```

```css
div.siblings {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="sibling" class="siblings">First sibling</div>
<div>Another component</div>
<div id="sibling2" class="siblings">Second sibling</div>
```

Here I have assigned the class `sibling` for both div and marked the CSS for it.

Answer (score 0):

jquery `append()` method will help you

```
$('#sibling2').append($('#sibling'));
```

you want to be the element in the same line, just set css properties of div to `display: inline-block;`

```
#sibling2, #sibling {
    display: inline-block;
}
```